# fullcalendar google hide past events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

how do I hide past events from being displayed in the fullcalender js api? This is how I am pulling calendar....

```js
$(function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('fullcalendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: ['dayGrid', 'list', 'googleCalendar'],
            header: {
                left: 'title',
                center: '',
                right: 'today prev,next'
            },
            defaultView: 'listYear',
            views: {
                activeStart: '2019-11-25'
                
            },
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(1,104,250, .15)',
            borderColor: '#0168fa',
            displayEventTime: true, 
            googleCalendarApiKey: '*********************************',
            events: { googleCalendarId: '************************@group.calendar.google.com' },

            eventClick: function (arg) {
                window.open(arg.event.url, '_blank', 'width=700,height=600');
            arg.jsEvent.preventDefault();
            }
        });
        calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: `views: {
                activeStart: '2019-11-25'
                
            }` ...what is this supposed to be? Doesn't match any syntax mentioned in the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-settings)

Comment: Anyway the simplest way to hide previous events is by making use of the [validRange](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange) setting

Comment: ADyson, you're correct, I was just searching madly on the internet for a solution and saw that somewhere.  I thought I had removed it before posting.

Comment: ADyson, validRange worked great.  Can you post it as an answer so I can award you credit?

Comment: By the way, I personally just discovered fullcalender yesterday, am I missing something or is there really no search functionality in the docs sections?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be, no. I just tend to put the docs in "list" mode (https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc) and then use Ctrl+F in the browser to find options. Not much use for searching within the doc pages though. Google has probably indexed it all though, so maybe that's the way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest way to hide previous events is by making use of the [validRange](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange) setting such that it always starts the valid range at the current date. You don't need to provide an end date if you don't want to.